# Glue Notebook not starting: Failed to start notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I'm getting the error:Failed to start notebook.

But already added to my role:

1. trust policy and pass policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"
        }]
        
}
```

2. and full access s3 and glue policies

I followed the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/notebook-getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today despite glue notebooks working fine for me yesterday. I then realised I was logged in with a different user with less access. So I'd say make sure your user you're logged into aws with has access to start up glue notebooks